# Bootstrap carousel Hyperlinks not working

Tags: css, hyperlink, bootstrap-4, carousel

am trying to have a carousel where each slide is linked to a different page.

My code for the base carousel is

```
 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <a href="about.html"> 
        <img src="img//tshirts/large/slide1.png" alt="" >

    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="tshirts.html"> 
        <img src="img//tshirts/large/slide2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="sublimation.html"> 
        <img src="img//tshirts/large/slide3.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="sweatshirts.html"> 
        <img src="img//tshirts/large/slide4.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

This works perfect and shows all 4 slides one after another then back to beginning
So I wanted to add the hyperlinks as follows

```
 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <a href="about.html"> 
        <img src="img//tshirts/large/slide1.png" alt="" >

    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="tshirts.html"> 
        <img src="img//tshirts/large/slide2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="sublimation.html"> 
        <img src="img//tshirts/large/slide3.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="sweatshirts.html"> 
        <img src="img//tshirts/large/slide4.png" alt="">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Now when I run the second code the first slide is perfect and when clicked goes to the page but as soon as it slides to the next slide no slide is shown and none are clickable and it doesn't go back to the first slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please close hyper link tag, Like

<div class="item active">
        <a href="about.html"> 
        <img src="img//tshirts/large/slide1.png" alt="" >
        </a>

    </div>
```